# Unable to get JSON data in Android

Tags: android, json

I want to send a `JSON` list from one activity to other. I am doing in this way

**For sending**

```
List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdapterContent.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("Array",jsonList.toString());
i.putExtras(b);
```

**For receiving**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String Array=b.getString("Array");
Log.i("TAG" ,Array);
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(Array);
Log.i("Name" , String.valueOf(jsonobj.getString("Name")));
```

**JSON Object**

```
[
{"Name":"Area1"},
{"Name":"Area 2"}
]
```

But it is prompting

> W/System.err:at com.example.data.mydata.onCreate

It is printing the `Array` but not the `Name` from `JsonObj`
Is anything wrong here?

Comment: use jsonobj.get("Name"), maybe it will help

Comment: What is your jsonList? Json Array or java Array ?

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur is right. What is the format are you getting in your `jsonObj` Show us the format through [pastie](http://pastie.org)

Comment: @masoudvali. `jsonobj.get("Name")` Not working

Comment: please show us the json you get from intent

Comment: @masoudvali See the jsonObject in question.

Comment: isn't it JSON array?

Comment: @vrundpurohit Yes it is.

Comment: one quick solution is that ,store your List in to preferences and access it where ever you want..

Comment: I am getting it from server and do not want to save it in shared preferences.

Comment: it is a json array not json object

Answer (score 2):

```
// make a json array
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(Array);

// empty containers for later use 
JSONObject jobj;
String name=null;

// traverse all json object according to index of jsonarray
for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++){

// fetch jasonObject according to index
  jobj=jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

// get the name string from object and use it accordingly 
  name=jobj.optString("Name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must cast the json string into json array not as json object

```
String Array = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Array");
Log.i("TAG" ,Array);
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(Array);
JSONObject jsonObj;
for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++){
  jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
  Log.i("Name" , String.valueOf(jsonObj.getString("Name")));
}
```

Note: it is recommended to serialize or convert the data to parcelable  while passing between activities

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to send `JsonList` . It's better to create a model class for your List.  and make it parcelable. and send it to another activity

```
intent.putExtra(Key,yourModelClass);
```